# Xamarion.iOS CoreBluetooth BLE app crashes on iPhone 10

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth

STEPS TO REPRODUCE CRASH...

1. Visual Studio on Windows 10, paired with macbook pro
2. Download wojciech-kulik/Sample-Projects from github: https://github.com/wojciech-kulik/Sample-Projects
3. open Sample-Projects-master\Xamarin.iOS\BluetoothTest\bLUETOOTH tEST.SLN
4. Pair with Mac
5. Select and debug on iPhone 10
   Crashes.
   See attached Output of crash.

iPhone is provisioned and runs my other Xamarin.iOS apps.

Have tried restarting all devices.

CRASH OUTPUT.........................................................
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/BluetoothTest2.exe

## =================================================================
Native Crash Reporting

## Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.

## =================================================================
Native stacktrace:

```
0x102ea23a8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
0x102e98620 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
0x102ea18f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BD03353-EB72-4E79-8D3B-F72606BA7DE9/BluetoothTest2.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : sigabrt_signal_handler
0x19c9aa894 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
0x19ca99e58 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>
0x19ca99e88 - /usr/lib/The app has been terminated.
```

system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : 
0x1a2f0dc64 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : 
0x1a2f0dba4 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : 
0x1a2f11ad8 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : 
0x19c874b1c - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : 
0x19c8693e8 - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : 
0x19c9675a4 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : 
0x19c93e0f8 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : 
0x19c94e1c0 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : 
0x19c9b8bac - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_wqthread
0x19c9bb740 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : start_wqthread

## =================================================================
Basic Fault Address Reporting

Memory around native instruction pointer (0x19ca957f4):0x19ca957e4  c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 30 41 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  ..*...*.0A...

...
0x19ca957f4  e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 b4 80 ff 97  ...T.{..........
0x19ca95804  bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6  .....{....*...*.
0x19ca95814  d0 03 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9  ..........
.T.{..

The app has been terminated.

Comment: Does your info.plist include the required privacy usage string for Bluetooth?

Comment: But it then gets a C# exception. What is the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the info.plist crash fix.   (But it then gets a C# exception)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>BluetoothTest</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>pl.wojciechkulik.BluetoothTest</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.3</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <!--for connecting to devices (client)-->
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>

        <!--for server configurations if needed-->
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>

    <!--Description of the Bluetooth request message (required on iOS 10, deprecated)-->
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>

    <!--Description of the Bluetooth request message (required on iOS 13)-->
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string></dict>
</plist>
```